# Is there any way to avoid being affected by an master merge from my colleagues' modules

Tags: git, puppet

We use **git+puppet** to develop our puppet codes and deploy them to our server nodes.

The technology diagram(including some Chinese but matters little) is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ufiq.jpg)

Common configurations like packages source list,dns servers ,and system related files is coding into puppet modules named with pkgmgr,networkmgr and sysenv.They are developing ,testing and releasing in different branches then pushed to /modules/env(branch)/common directory on puppet master node. On the other hand,we have many projects having their own  configurations,including or declaring common modules,coding into a module named after project name and then copied to modules/env(branch)/projects in the same way.

Servers in every project acting as puppet agent can be set a specific puppet environment like production,testing.For example when the production environment is selected, the resources from modules defined in /modules/production/common and /modules/production/projects/project_A will be deployed.

Common modules is maintained by another apartment , any update merged to master branch will affect our projects servers in production environment.Is there any way to satisfy:

> 1 Some of our projects servers do not want any update anymore before they are offline
>
> 2 Any change to common modules will generate a tagged snapshot like version and can be selected by our project positively

I know is hard to release puppet module in version like other offline softwares,but any way else to satisfy the two requirements elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Release management of software can be tricky with lots of teams.

My recommendation is don't use the same repository, if you can use one repository per module (although this can introduce quite a bit of overhead). Instead you can just use multiple git repositories and vendor your companies "common" modules in using say librarian-puppet.

Comment: Ok...Do you mean providing common modules separately and offline? Just like download modules from puppet forge ? Then the question is how to arrange them under puppet modules directory and allow us to select the specific version

Comment: That's what librarian-puppet will do for you. You can point it at puppet forge or a git repo, if you use a git repo you can select a branch, tag or SHA as your version. Librarian puppet will automatically place these modules in your module directory (although I prefer to keep them in vendor/modules, so I know which ones are mine and which are upstream)

Comment: It makes sense. And I am going to try it practically and tell you if there is other problems. thank you.